# Simic Manipulator and polymorphist's jest combo

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Once [Polymorhist Jest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433022) is cast by an opponent during your attacking phase can a defending player also legally take full control over a target creature by tapping [Simic Manipulator’s](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366343) ability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only interaction between Polymorphic Jest and Simic Manipulator is that Polymorphic Jest can reduce a creature’s power, which reduces the number of counters you must remove from Simic in order to take control of it. So after Polymorphic Jest resolves; all the opponent’s creatures will be a 1/1 until end of turn, meaning that Simic can take control of one of them by removing just 1 counter.